# std::is_copy_constructable for std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, sfinae, incomplete-type

I recently read [this blogpost](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/02/05/vector-is-copyable-except-when-its-not/) on why vector has to be unconditionally copyable so it can support incomplete types. I understand that this is necessary also from a logical point of view, since the following has a circular dependency on copyability:

```
struct Test {
    std::vector<Test> v;
};
```

Now I thought about, whether or not one could at least try to give the best information available. In other words, `std::vector<T>` is copy constructable if and only if `T` is copy constructable or incomplete. So `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` would never be copy constructible since `std::unique_vector` is move-only, independent of `T`.

I came to the following solution:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>


template<class T, class = decltype(sizeof(int))>
struct is_complete : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_complete<T, decltype(sizeof(T))> : std::true_type{};

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_complete_v = is_complete<T>::value;

// Indirection to avoid instantiation of is_copy_constructible with incomplete type
template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<is_complete_v<T>>>
struct copyable {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>;
};

template<class T>
struct copyable<T, void> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
struct Container {

    template<class T1 = T, class = std::enable_if_t<copyable<T1>::value>>
    Container(const Container &) {}
};

struct A;
struct B{};

static_assert(!is_complete_v<A>);
static_assert(is_complete_v<B>);
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Container<A>>);
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Container<B>>);
static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::unique_ptr<A>>);
static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::unique_ptr<B>>);

struct A{};

static_assert(!is_complete_v<A>);
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aaUvA4)
(All `static_assert`s compile)

Now I have three questions (sorry if they are a bit unrelated):

1. Is this code valid standard C++ or does it rely on undefined behavior anywhere?
2. What do you think about this idea?
3. I first had for the copy constructor the SFINAE condition `!is_complete_v<T1> || std::is_copy_constructible_v<T1>` but I had to add indirection because otherwise clang (not gcc) would not compile due to `std::is_copy_constructible` being instantiated with an incomplete type. Does `||` not also short-circuit the instantiation of templates?

Regarding 1., in my opinion there should be no UB. The one part where it could happen is `sizeof(T)`, since one should not use that with an incomplete type. But SFINAE-ing with `sizeof` has a long tradition from when it was the only unevaluated context, so I would think that is ok.

Regarding 2., I know that this makes whether or not a `vector<T>` is copy constructible very fragile, since if one adds a forward declaration of an otherwise complete `T` somewhere at an unrelated part of the code and then also checks it completeness, this will change the completeness of `T` for the whole project. I am not sure if the small increase in available information is worth this.

Comment: Not directly in your code, but I think you need to at least put everything in an unnamed namespace to give it internal linkage, otherwise a different translation unit could easily cause an ODR violation, which also means that you won't be able to use the container across translation unit boundaries.

Comment: @walnut The test code shown here would benefit by being in a separate source file, and not the header with the rest of it.  The templates should be global and not in an unnamed namespace, and ODR violations should not be a problem.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Suppose the templates are all in a header file and we have two translation units including it, but one includes only a forward declaration `struct A;` and the other the full definition of `A` which is non-copyable. Then using `std::is_copy_constructible_v<Container<A>>` in both units causes instantiation of the same class template with two different definitions in the two translation units, because e.g.`std::enable_if_t<copyable<T1>::value>` will not refer to the same template specialization according to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6.2.

Comment: @walnut Sounds like that'd just be changing one type of error for another, if your two different translation units with the local namespaces have the same code but different behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> necessary also from a logical point of view, since the following has a circular dependency on copyability:
>
> ```
> struct Test {
>     std::vector<Test> v;
> };
> ```

That doesn't make it logically necessary. Function `a` can call function `b` which calls function `a`. It is necessary given the premise that you have to answer the question when the declaration of v is encountered inside the declaration of Test. In current C++ as we know it, it is necessary, but that follows from the various rules we ourselves impose.

> Is this code valid standard C++ or does it rely on undefined behavior anywhere?

UB. Template specializations cannot have different meaning at different points of instantiation. Specifically, a "... static data member of a class template may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit" including always the end [temp.point/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#7). The compiler is free to instantiate `is_complete<T>::value` at the end of the translation unit, in addition to the other places. The program is ill-formed if this gives a different answer at different instantiation points.

So you cannot instantiate `is_complete` with a type which is incomplete but will later be complete, like `Test`.